# Using amazon API Gateway to access full permissions on amazon dynamodb

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I implemented a custom authorizer in AWS lambda with the following input in JSON:

```
{
    "type":"TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken":"<session_token>",
    "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:<region>:<Account_ID>:<API_ID>/<Stage>/<Method>/<Resource_Path>"
}
```

How do I use the cusom authrozier from my IOS app (I know how to call it from the app) to access full tables in AWS DynamoDB?

Thanks.